# Confusion in set-theory: Definition of formulas needs set

Tags: logic, set-theory

I am confused about some definitions in logic/ axiomatic set theory:

We stated in our logic lecture the ZFC axioms and called the members of a ZFC-model "sets".
But to define formulas and structures, we needed sets as in "A structure is a non-empty set with functions and relations" and also for formulas, we needed, e. g. a variable set.

Could you help me solving my problem? For me it currently seems circle-reasoning.

Best regards

Comment: I believe that there are a few threads like this one on this site already.

Comment: Here is one: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/121128/when-does-the-set-enter-set-theory

Comment: You are confusing the word "set" with the word "set".

Comment: I really recommend checking out Asaf's link. Further, I'd say that one can eliminate the notion of a set from the syntax of a first-order language by adopting a weaker meta-theory, say primitive recursive arithmetic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no circularity here: just an usual confusion between **metalanguage** and **object language**, or, more precisely, between the English-language word 'set' and the object-theoretic word '$set$' in ZFC. What you have observed is that in order "to define the formulas and structures" *in* ZFC we need to dispose of sets in our mathematical universe of the meta-language (to which extent this assumption is innocent is a question for the philosopher of mathematics).

Tourkalis makes an illuminating analogy in his *Lectures in Logic and Set Theory I* (2003) distinguishing those two levels of abstraction:

> This is analogous to building a "model airplane", a replica of the real thing, with a view of studying through the replica the properties, power, and limitations of the real thing. (p.3)